# react-router-sitemap creates duplicate entries

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, sitemap

Is there a way to prevent react-router-sitemap from creating duplicate entries for the same URL?

For example, it creates a sitemap like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mobile="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
<url> <loc>https://www.example.com/</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>https://www.example.com/ui</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>https://www.example.com/ui</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>https://www.example.com/about</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>https://www.example.com/about</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>https://www.example.com/sign-up</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>https://www.example.com/sign-up</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>https://www.example.com/imprint</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>https://www.example.com/imprint</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>https://www.example.com/</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>https://www.example.com/</loc> </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: I've hit upon the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I never found a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with after long struggle, basically bypassing the automatic generation of sitemap routes in `react-router-sitemap`. I saved the script below as **sitemap-generator.js**. Added in **package.json** a script:  `"sitemap": "babel-node sitemap-generator.js"`, and then with npm run sitemap update the sitemap. **src/routes.js** is the routes declaration (via BrowserRouter) exported as default.

```
/**
 * sitemap-generator.js 
 */

 
require('@babel/register')({
    extends: './.babelrc',
})

/**   
 * Avoid trouble with special imports
 */

require.extensions['.png'] = function () {
    return null;
};
require.extensions['.jpg'] = function () {
    return null;
};
require.extensions['.css'] = function () {
    return null;
}; 

// imports for sitemap creation & xml saving
import {createSitemap } from 'sitemap'; // import createSitemap
import path from 'path';
import fs   from 'fs'; 

// routes, hostname & xml destination.  
const router   = require('./src/routes').default;
const hostname = 'http://localhost:3000';
const dest     = path.resolve('./public', 'sitemap.xml');

// import from 
const routePaths  = router.props.children.props.children;
const paths       = []; // we will append links here
routePaths.map(route => {
    const path = route.props.path;
    if (path !== "*") {
        let currentPath = {
            url: path,
            changefreq: "daily",
            priority: 0.5
        }           
        paths.push(currentPath);
    }
})
    
const sitemap = createSitemap({
    hostname,
    urls: paths
}) 

// write sitemap.xml file in /public folder
fs.writeFileSync(dest, sitemap.toString())
```

Now the routes definition in **src/routes.js**. This was a little tricky for me too.

```
/**
 * Routes setup
 * 
 */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

/* Pages */
import HomePage from "./pages/home"; 
import ContactPage from "./pages/contacto";
import Page404 from "./pages/404";

/* Object for local consumption & Sitemap Generator */
const Routedef = (
    <BrowserRouter basename = {process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
        <Switch>            
            <Route key="1" exact path="/"         component={HomePage} />
            <Route key="2" exact path="/contact"  component={ContactPage} />                                    
            <Route key="0"       path="*"         component={Page404} />                                    
        </Switch>        
    </BrowserRouter>
)

/**
 * Return to App.js
 */
function AppRoutes()  {
    return (Routedef)
}

// exports
export default Routedef
export {AppRoutes}
```